# PHP and MySql using PDO 'String data, right truncated' Error after insert image in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am pretty new to PHP and MySql and am having trouble with I think a LongBlob column in my DB. the entire error is here

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01004]: String data, right truncated' in Client.php:110 Stack trace: #0 Client.php(110): Client::FindByOwnerID() #1 User.php(91): Client->FindByOwnerID('2') #2 UserController.php(26): User->FindByID('2') #3 {main} thrown in Client.php on line 110
```

I only seem to get this error if I upload an image to a LongBlob column. If I delete the row with the image everything works great.

I am using PDO to connect to to my database, I have searched for a solution but have only found similar problems that do not seem to mention anything about Images...

Is this a SQL Config issue, am I missing a PDO attribute?

Here is my PDO code

```
$dbConnString = "mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";port=".DB_PORT."; dbname=" . DB_DATABASE;
$this->dbConnection = new PDO($dbConnString, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);        
$this->dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$this->dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Do not store image in database! Store it in the file system & then save the image path in the db.

Comment: Well, how big is the image? Are you sure it's a longblob column? The column's size commands how big the data can be that you're storing in it. (And what Sumoanand says)

Comment: Image is about 60KB. Yes the column is definitely a longblob, this is what I see next to the browse button in PHPMyAdmin (Max: 1,024 MiB) so 60KB should be fine. As for storing in the DB, in SQLServer I do this all the time with no issues. With MySQL is it not  a great idea then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personaly prefer not to store images in database but if you need to : check the image size it if it exceeds 1MB you have to increase the max_allowed_packet option in the server configuration file. You can change that in the Startup Variables section in the MySQL Administrator on the Networking page.

Check this link

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/program-variables.html

Comment: Thanks, based on the other comments I will probably refactor a bit to store the images on the filesystem as suggested. Eventually there will be a ton of them so I guess this is probably better.